# Mongodb: Transform a date range to array of date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hy,
I have some documents with a start date and a end date.

```
{
  startDate: ISODate("2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
  endDate: ISODate("2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Is it possible using mongodb aggregations to have something like

```
[
  ISODate("2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
  ISODate("2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
  ISODate("2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
  ISODate("2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")
]
```

The goal is to intersect two date range in order to extract common date.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `$range` (similar to `for` loop) operator. Main idea:

```
for(i=0; i<difference(endDate - startDate); i++){
    startDate + (i * `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`)
}
```

> `difference(endDate - startDate)` returns time differences in milliseconds, so we need to divide `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      range: {
        $range: [
          0,
          {
            $add: [
              {
                $divide: [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      "$endDate",
                      "$startDate"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $multiply: [
                      24,
                      60,
                      60,
                      1000
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      result: {
        $map: {
          input: "$range",
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$startDate",
              {
                $multiply: [
                  "$$this",
                  24,
                  60,
                  60,
                  1000
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

```
{
  "result" : [ 
      ISODate("2020-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      ISODate("2020-01-08T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      ISODate("2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      ISODate("2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z")
  ]
}
```